# Problem number of decimals after calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with the number of decimals after a calculation in SQL Server.
All numeric fields have the datatype `decimal(10,4)`, however when I do a calculations sometimes it rounds at 5 decimals precision.

This is my query:

```
select rp.ReceptProduct_ID,p.Product_ID, P.Product_Omschrijving, sum(Recept_Hoeveelheid*Prijs) as Totaal
from Product p
inner join ReceptProduct rp
on p.Product_ID=rp.Product_ID
inner join VerpakkingProduct vp
on p.Product_ID=vp.Product_ID
inner join VerpakkingWinkel vw
on vp.Verpakking_ID=vw.Verpakking_ID
group by rp.ReceptProduct_ID,p.Product_ID, P.Product_Omschrijving
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [Precision, scale and length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If you provide a [mre] we can give you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

Addition and subtraction preserve scale and precision.  Multiplication and division do not.  The precision of the result is tricky.

If you really care, cast to the scale/precision you want *after* the operation.  You can consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the specific rules.

Comment: YOur statements conflict here, Gordon. *"multiplication preserve scale and precision. Multiplication and division do not."* which is it? :)

Comment: @Larnu pretty sure he meant "Addition and Subtraction" which would be correct.

Comment: I assume so as well, @SeanLange ,but I'd rather not make an edit that could conflict with his intent.

Comment: @Larnu - Agreed.